# 'Save as' dialogue box in Vista/Win7

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

Is there a way to get this box to list the local and network drives first instead of listing favorites and libraries first?  I have a user who claims this is how this box was until fairly recently but I have not made any changes nor pushed out any big updates.  Now that he mentions it, its starting to bug me too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just add the resources to your "Favorites" Library and that should have them show up.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, there's a useful utility that allows you to fully customise what you have in the 'save as' container [Places](http://www.simplisoftware.com/Public/index.php?request=Places)

Comment: Is it compatible with W7 32 and 64 bit?

Comment: The link is dead...